# Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor, setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, array given

Tags: magento2.4, php-7.3, php-7.4

After clear/setting/configuring so many errors & configurations installed the **Magento V2.4.1** successfully, now getting below errors.

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor, setcookie() expects
> parameter 3 to be integer, array given

and

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor, setcookie() expects
> parameter 3 to be integer, array given

I have ran the instance both **PHP7.3** and **PHP7.4** but getting same error. First time in the browser showing website, If I navigate any other page getting error continuously.

[image]

Continuously getting error and unable to open the backend and store front.

[image]

Help on this?

Comment: The error might be related to your php version, if you use a version >= 7.3 the error shouldn't occur.since the signature of setcookie with the third parameter of type array was added in php version 7.3

Comment: @HelgeB Yes, I am using `PHP 7.3.23-4+ubuntu18.04.1`. But not working. Any help?

Comment: @HelgeB The same error showing after upgraded `PHP 7.4` also.

Comment: does phpversion() returns the same version if you call it from CLI and via URL? What webserver do you use? If it's apache and you are using mod-php you should check that too

Comment: @HelgeB let me check.

Comment: @HelgeB Having multiple PHP Versions in my system. So enabled the PHP7.4 Version through terminal. `PHPVersion()` will show loaded file by default of **7.1** version.

Comment: So the issue was with incorrect php version used during running magento on web server and now it solved?

Comment: Thank you **HelgeB** and **IhorSviziev** Yes, php version is the issue. now working fine.

Answer (score 6):

Just had this problem on a server. It was solved after I changed the nginx config to (before it was 7.2):

upstream fastcgi_backend {
server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

And restarted nginx..

Comment: its works for me

Comment: Thanks. working for me

Comment: Thanks. working for me

Answer (score 1):

The issue is occurred due to the PHP older version. Check the PHP version `print phpversion();`.

Disable older version

```
sudo a2dismod php7.x
```

Enable PHP 7.4

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

and restart apache2

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

It's working good in my case

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands and check

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -rf generated/code/  var/view_preprocessed/ var/page_cache

php  bin/magento  cache:clean
php  bin/magento  cache:flush

Hope, your error will be solved.